# change background color and a view color inside a listview row when touched

Tags: android, listview, view

I need to change a row view background color to blue, it's something like this:
[image]

the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="@dimen/main_info_cell_view_width"
android:layout_height="@dimen/main_info_cell_view_height"
android:background="@color/main_info_cell_background_color" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/pic_frame"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/channel_pic_background_widht"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/channel_pic_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/main_info_cell_pic_background_color" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/channel_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/c__no_image" />
</FrameLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/main_info_cell_divider_widht"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pic_frame"
    android:background="@color/main_info_cell_divider_color" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/title_margin_left"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/title_margin_right"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/title_margin_top"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/divider"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="2"
    android:textColor="@color/main_info_cell_title_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/time_margin_bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/time_margin_left"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/divider"
    android:textColor="@color/main_info_cell_time_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/time_text_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pos_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/pos_nr_margin_right"
    android:textColor="@color/main_info_cell_pos_nr_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/pos_nr_size" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried using a selector for the row but the problem is that the selector changes only the background color of the view and the black square that is under the ImageView still remains black, how can i change its color along with the row background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `StateListDrawable` as your background to the root/parent `ViewGroup` of the hierarchy.

Thus, `android:background="@drawable/mystatelistdrawable"` where `mystatelistdrawable` is the file laid out using [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

You might also want to look at [`android:duplicateParentState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aduplicateParentState).

Comment: android:duplicateParentState doesnt work, and a stateListDrawable is allready set for the viewgroup the problem is how do i change the child view background color along with the parent background when touched

Comment: I must have missed where the StateListDrawable was set in the above layout. Where is it?

Comment: Oh sorry i added it in code) anyway it can set it in xml its the same effect

Comment: And what does that file look like (containing the selector)?

Comment: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/select_color" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cellbackground"/>

</selector>